# POST HTML <form> to external aspx page

Tags: c#, .net, http, response.redirect, server.transfer

I have already read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209301/how-to-post-a-form-from-html-to-aspx-page). However, in my case the page I am posting to is an external *.aspx* page.

Basically I generate *XML* data on the source page code with `XElement`, and need to *POST* that to an external *.aspx* page. The requirement say it needs to be wrapped in HTML `</form>` tag before posting. So my string in the code-behind file looks like

```
<FORM id="frmLogin" action="https://illustration.sagicorlifeusa.com/fse5/main/FormPost.aspx" method="post" target=blank>

    <XML>myxml<XML\>

    <input type="submit" name="__exclude__Submit" value="Run Sagicor Life Illustration Software Online     ">
</form>
```

Now on the code-behind file, what is it that I need to do, to post this to the external *.aspx* page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a hidden input, set its value in codebehind and post the form to the destination page so that on that page the value can be extracted back. Did i understand your question?

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make sense. You normally don't post HTML code.

You should check the requirement for what they really want. My guess is that you would put it in an HTML tag if you post it from the browser, but that would not apply if you post it from the server.