# Passing username and password from HTML Page to ASPX page?

Tags: html, asp.net

How can i send Usename and password from Login.HTML Page to default.aspx from HTML, and how can i read username and password in default.aspx(c#) page sanded by Login.html page.

Comment: This is a very basic question have you searched on google?
go to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209301/how-to-post-a-form-from-html-to-aspx-page

Answer (score 0):

Login.htm

```
<form action="Default.aspx">
   user name: <input type="text" id="txtusername" name="txtusername" />
   Password: <input type="password" id="txtpass" name="txtpass" />
   <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostback)
    {
       string username = Request["txtusername"];
       string password = Request["txtpass"];
       // remaing code
    }
}
```