# html form to aspx login

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm trying to forward login data from a HTML form to an aspx login page. The idea is to create a single sign on button for a website that stores the users login user name and password, and when they click "sign in" they are then logged into the websites aspx page. We do not have access to this companies back-end, so I'm wondering if it's possible to just create a form on our end that stores the user login data, and then forwards the login data to the form when a button is pressed.

Comment: You simply direct your form to wherever you want the data to go, with the `action` attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to POST a FORM from HTML to ASPX page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209301/how-to-post-a-form-from-html-to-aspx-page)

Comment: @obsidian age I tried that, but the login does not process the data. Is it possible that on their side maybe aspx disables or does some check to make sure data inst being passed over?