# html form post to an aspx page, the header fields are not being posted. Chrome says the request is a GET, and does not show Form Data at all

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, web, post

Here is the posting page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Properties login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="formstart"  method="POST" action="proplist.aspx">
        <table id="loginTable" class="center">
            <tr>
                <td><label >User name</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="usertext" text="asm"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label ID="passwd" >Password</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="passtext" text=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label ID="Label2" >Press to continue</label></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Simple html, no asp in case that causes any problem.
Here is the target aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="proplist.aspx.cs" Inherits="PropertyW.proplist" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="formlist" runat="server">

         <div>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Comic Sans MS" Font-Size="Larger" ForeColor="#3333CC" Text="Property List"></asp:Label>
            <div id="loginResponse" runat="server" >not logged in
        </div>
         <div id="namePassed" runat="server"></div>
 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code behind.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace PropertyW
{
    public partial class proplist : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
                string userName = "asm", password = "17kgrovE";
                string sName = Request.Form["usertext"];
                string sPass = nvc["passtext"];
                if (nvc.Count > 0)
                {
                    sName = nvc["usertext"] + ".nvc";
                }
                string sMsg = string.Format("name passed = {0}, nvc count = {1}", sName, nvc.Count);
                namePassed.InnerHtml = sMsg;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sName))
                {
                    userName = sName;
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sPass))
                {
                    password = sPass;
                }
                // CheckLogin(userName, password);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what chrome shows in the network tab.  There is no entry for the Form data.
In the code behind the form fields are null.  (usertext and passtext).
Chrome shows the request as a GET even though the code is a POST.

[Here is what chrome shows in the network tab.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVSSk.png)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/22559051/5519709 it may helps to you.

Comment: Thanks for this. Does not help though, still does not work. I have decided to just use a button calling the code behind, and do a redirect from there.